# Different numbering prefixes on the same header level

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have different sections in a document that use the same level of heading, Heading 3 in this case. The headings for each section need to have a numbering system with a prefix of A, B, C, etc. I am able to setup numbering with a prefix, but I can't get the prefix to change between each section. Is there a way to do this while using the built in numbering tools?

#### A1. A Header

#### A2. A Header

#### B1. B Header

#### B2. B Header

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/290953), it doesn't seem possible. They say:

> Microsoft Word does not support multiple heading-numbering schemes in
>   a single document or master document. When you work with documents
>   that contain both chapter headings and appendix headings, the headings
>   must not use the same heading style level.

It would seem that the sections you have are analogous to chapters vs appendix in their example. Obviously, their proposal of having different headings for each section doesn't scale very well. :(

Comment: Thank you very much! I was unable to find this information on their site. Once I am able, I will mark this as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the headings you want by using different heading styles - where Heading 1 is set to use A,B,C etc. and Heading 2 1,2,3.
If you insist on using the same heading style you have to manually type your letters for each section in the numbering box, and set the drop-down Apply From (or something like that, in the top right of the numbering dialog) to 'This point forward'.